# How to set repeated task with a random interval in PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, timer, cron, schedule

Is there any smart way for me to set a repeated task with random time interval.

Say like if I want to do task A every time in range of 3 mins to 5 mins
Example:

1st Task A - 3 mins
2nd Task A - 4 mins
3rd Task A - 5 mins
4th Task A - 4 mins
...

---

Finally My solution is laravel Queue jobs 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: `php artisan make:job dosomething`  then in the controller `$this->dispatch(dosomething)->everyFiveMinutes()`  in a nutshell.

Comment: Please Review the **Task Scheduling** (i.e https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling) Documents.

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi I have checked the document roughly and cant see anything related to random interval. It seems that its easy to exectue repeated task with standard interval but not dynamic intervalk

Comment: For random interval, just make it every minute but in every of those minutes, determine randomly whether you should do or not?

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata, that s a possible solution. But after that , the interval can only be 3,4 or 5 mins. But it cannot achieve like real random in range of 3 mins and 5 mins , such as 3 mins and 30s

Comment: A second based random range can also be built in the same way.

Comment: Do you want a random interval between end of previous task and start of new task or a random interval between start of previous task and start of new task?

Comment: @kvantour I want a random interval between end of previous task and start of new task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use scheduler 
Here is link: [Laravel Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)

Use of scheduler makes code clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple way.

1) You can use crontab. Make a cron of you task and add in your crontab with interval of 5 mins.

2) If you want to handle with php only, than you have to add `sleep` in infinite while `loop` as shown below. Run script in nohup as process. So it will continuously run in background.

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while(1){
    //Perform you task A here.


    if($i == 0){ 
        $sleep = 180;   
        $i = 1;
    }else{
        $sleep = 300;   
        $i = 0;
    }   

    sleep($sleep);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but can I make a cron with different interval every time ? Say like five mins in this time but three mins in next time

Comment: hi perter, For cron you need to specify two different expression. Which will run independently in different interval (5 and 3 mins). If you want to handle in php, you can check above code i have made changes. Above code will run first 3 min and after 5 min . The same cycle will run for infinite (till you stop).

Comment: say like the case is round number 
The round number increase 1 after dynamic duration
Will sleep, the above approach create any undesired behaviours ?
Appreciate your suggestion !

Comment: The above code will only works if you will run for single task. But if you want to run multiple task, It will better to go with crontab. Because it will increase you complexity in php.